# How to validate a username and password using textFieldDidChange using Objective C?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

```
-(void)select
{

    NSString *sql1= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM sample"];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql1 UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        while( sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW )
        {

            char *field1=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0 );
            NSString *field1Str=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field1];
            NSLog(@"The string value is %@ ",field1Str);
            char *field2=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,1 );
            NSString *field2Str=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field2];
            NSLog(@"The string value is %@ ",field2Str);
            [self.usertext1 addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

            -(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)_usertext1{

            if([_usertext1.text isEqualToString:field1Str]&&[_passtext2.text isEqualToString:field2Str])
            {
                _outbutton.enabled="YES";            }
            else
            {
                _outbutton.enabled="NO";
            }                
        }
    }}    
}
```

I am new to iOS programming. I have tried above code for validating username and password while user will type. I don't no how to use `textFieldDidChange` and `forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged`. I just want to make my login page more secure and efficient. If I type correct values or wrong value the control goes to next page. How can I validate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you class you will need to import the delegate from text field.

`@interface ClassName : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>`

Put the `textFieldDidChange` function outside the function `select`.

And finally on `viewDidLoad` you need to set `self.usertext1.delegate = self;` this should be enough to get the changes from your text field.

You will always use Delegate to identify changes from view elements or anything else that happened on an undefined time.